# Java JPA: refresh entity modifications

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa

Is there any way to cancel not-merged modifications of a managed entity ?

some kind of refresh to read its state from database and loose the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refresh()` method from [Entity Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html).

Comment: I the operation should fail, which is the case

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `refresh()` in the `EntityManager` class located [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)) which will do what you want.